# Running an Activity that requires permission to access the gallery

Tags: android

I have this activity that is supposed to access the gallery and choose an image. It run with zero errors but when pressing the "choose " button I got a Permission Denied response in accessing the gallery. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is normal. You have to [request permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to access Gallery

Comment: Please consider, posting your code :)

Comment: Thanks @AlyssaGono for the edit. I have changed the title to sentence case, as that tends to be preferred here.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374551/read-and-write-external-storage-permission-isnt-working

Comment: maybe be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360763/permission-denied-when-creating-new-file-on-external-storage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read and Write external storage permission isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374551/read-and-write-external-storage-permission-isnt-working)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, Please try to search your problem first before asking a question. this question already have answers many time

Answer (score 1):

If you are target app marshmallow or above you need to add run time permission.

Try below code

Add Permission in your Manifest using below line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And use below code for get run time permission

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

For more detail please prefer below link

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.