# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE shows permission but not READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, permissions, storage, android-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying gaining permission reading and writing on the external storage:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code for asking for permission:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  //works. dialog pops up
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
  //doesnt work. dialog does not pop
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},  565);
}
```

But I have an issue: The issue is that I am only "allowed" to allow permission for reading the storage, not writing in this. The dialog does pop up when asking for writer permissions. Am I missing something? I know that u have to ask for the permission if the sdk version is higher than marshmellow. The permission ask also happens during runtime (onClick listener).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374551/read-and-write-external-storage-permission-isnt-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by adding tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest have to add these line after adding line you can show all data

requestLegacyExternalStorage=true